# why would adding a crossover private nic cause IP address resource fail?

Tags: windows, sql, cluster, msdtc

- 2 node Win 2008 R2 quorum cluster
- Configured 192.168.0.0/24 "public network"
- Configured cluster MSDTC
- Installed SQL 2008 R2 cluster instance
- Manually failover groups - OK
- Reboot server w/o failing over groups - failover OK
- Pull public network cable from one node - failover OK
- Added crossover cable 10.2.0.0/24 "private network"
- Verified ping on private network
- Verified file share browse on private network to C$ admin shares
- Pull public network cable from one node - MSDTC IP address resource fails on original host rather than failing over
- Manually moved MSDTC group to other node - everything onlines normally
- Reseat public network cable on node 1 & verified everything online on node 2
- Pull public network cable from node 2 - MSDTC and SQL IP address resources fail on original host rather than failing over
- Reseat public network cable on node 2 and manually fail all resources back and forth - OK
- Reboot server w/o failing over groups - failover OK
- Removed crossover cable private network and disabled private network NIC's (only single public network remains)
- Pull public network cable from one node - everything including MSDTC fails over normally

Several people have told me in the aftermath not to do a cable pull test - anyone have any documentation on why and potential impact?  Just saying MVP says so won't fly with manager w/o documentation.

More importantly, why would adding a crossover cable have this kind of impact?

Comment: Why did they say not to do the cable pull test?

Comment: I consider pulling the cables to be a necessary test to validating the functionality of the cluster.

Comment: I believe you're seeing a split-brain scenario.

Answer (score 3):

The private interconnect between two cluster nodes serves a dual purpose: to verify that the nodes can see *each other*, and to verify that each node *has a working private connection*.

MS Cluster Service requires both of these checks to pass, or it will proclaim the node unreliable, and refuse to fail over, reasoning (quite correctly) that ***not*** changing anything in an unknown situation is better than failing over in an unknown situation - possibly to a failed node.

If the private NIC fails, that node automatically assumes itself unsuitable for failover, and effectively exits the cluster.

If both ends of the private connection are plugged into a switch, these tests become indepedent of each other, and each node can safely fail its private connection, without the **other** node failing as well.

Moral of the story: crossover cables are bad, and best left to amateurs.

Comment: "If both ends of the private connection are plugged into a switch, these tests become indepedent of each other, and each node can safely fail its private connection, without the other node failing as well."  << That's what I was looking for - I didn't like the crossover cable idea (I know switch is better) but was trying to make the best of a bad situation - I thought it would be better than just having a single public network....what I was looking for was the *why* - thanks!

Comment: ...yes, that's what i said ;)

Comment: Does NLB support dual heartbeat? Surely you can also heartbeat over the main link.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a crossover cable directly between your cluster nodes, of course the IP address resource will fail - pulling the connection from one node will also cause the other node to see the NIC go to an 'unplugged' status - therefore how can it bring the IP resource up on the  other node?