# Re-Ask - why would adding a crossover private nic cause IP address resource fail?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, sql, cluster

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why would adding a crossover private nic cause IP address resource fail?](https://serverfault.com/questions/378864/why-would-adding-a-crossover-private-nic-cause-ip-address-resource-fail)

- 2 node Win 2008 R2 quorum cluster
- Configured 192.168.0.0/24 "public network"
- Configured cluster MSDTC
- Installed SQL 2008 R2 cluster instance
- Manually failover groups - OK
- Reboot server w/o failing over groups - failover OK
- Pull public network cable from one node - failover OK
- Added crossover cable 10.2.0.0/24 "private network"
- Verified ping on private network
- Verified file share browse on private network to C$ admin shares
- Pull public network cable from one node - MSDTC IP address resource fails on original host rather than failing over
- Manually moved MSDTC group to other node - everything onlines normally
- Reseat public network cable on node 1 & verified everything online on node 2
- Pull public network cable from node 2 - MSDTC and SQL IP address resources fail on original host rather than failing over
- Reseat public network cable on node 2 and manually fail all resources back and forth - OK
- Reboot server w/o failing over groups - failover OK
- Removed crossover cable private network and disabled private network NIC's (only single public network remains)
- Pull public network cable from one node - everything including MSDTC fails over normally

Several people have told me in the aftermath not to do a cable pull test - anyone have any documentation on why and potential impact?  Just saying MVP says so won't fly with manager w/o documentation.

More importantly, why would adding a crossover cable have this kind of impact?

NOTE: When I asked this question once before ([why would adding a crossover private nic cause IP address resource fail?](https://serverfault.com/questions/378864/why-would-adding-a-crossover-private-nic-cause-ip-address-resource-fail)) someone answered "of course they fail" - the key to me is that the resources do not [offline/failover to other node/online]....they just FAIL when the crossover cable network (on a different subnet from the public network) is in the mix....removing the crossover cable network allows the failovers to happen properly (pull the pubic cable from node 1 and everything [offlines/fails over/onlines] successfully.)

HELP!

Comment: As you say, this is an exact duplicate of your previous question.  Re-posting it isn't the solution.  Ask the answerer of the previous question for more details using the comments.